# why ruby loop does not exit

Tags: ruby, do-while

I'm trying to write a loop that exits at a certain value of an integer variable.

```
i=2
while i != 5 do
    puts "insert an integer. 5 to end"
    i = gets.chomp
    puts "you entered #{i}"
end

puts "program end"
```

the program keeps asking puts "insert an integer. 5 to end" even if I insert 5

the same story with loop do

```
i=2
loop do 
  puts "insert an integer. 5 to end"
    i = gets.chomp
    puts "you entered #{i}"
  break if i == 5
end 
puts "program end"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets.chomp` returns a `String`, so `i` is never equal to `5`, a `Fixnum`. You need to convert it to an integer:

```
i = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Answer (score 4):

```
i=2
while i != "5" do
    puts "insert an integer. 5 to end"
    i = gets.chomp
    puts "you entered #{i}"
end

puts "program end"
```

You're getting a string from the user, therefore `i != 5` always evaluates to false. You can turn it to `i != "5"` or convert your string to an integer.